# How to pass and retrieve data over the url in React

Tags: reactjs

I cannot figure out how to link to a specific product in my simple e-commerce site in React. The documentation makes it seem simple enough but it's all for classes rather than functional components like I am using so maybe that is where my problem is.

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
<Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Main} />
          <Route path="/:book" component={Single} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Main.js

```
const Main = () => {

  return (
    <div id="main">
      {data.map((book, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i} className="squares">
            <img
              src={images[book.picture]}
              className="covers"
              alt="book cover"
            />
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            <h3>
              **<Link to="/:book">{book.title}</Link>**
            </h3>
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            <p>
              Author: <em>{book.author}</em>
            </p>
            <p>
              Price: <strong>{book.price}$</strong>
            </p>
            <p>{book.inventory} left in stock</p>
          </div>
```

Single.js

```
const Single = (props) => {
  let { book } = useParams();
  console.log(book); //prints :book
```

I know it's typically this.props.match.params.book so I figured I would just need to leave off the 'this' but obviously I am missing something. I have tried it before my function, in my function, anything I could think of. Are objects not allowed to be passed in the url?

Comment: please provide entire code.

Comment: Objects can be passed as state in react-router-v5, 
history,push(URL,{. ...STATE })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up coming from here -

```
 <Link to="/:book">{book.title}</Link>
```

This is the exact format that the React Docs gave and everyone who attempted to help me copied this error which is why none of the given answers worked for me. This link sent me to localhost:3000/:book because that is the literal string.

The answer I needed was

```
 <Link to={`/${i}`}>>{book.title}</Link>
```

You'll note that I am passing the id instead of the object itself. It is also possible to pass the object but in my case the best way was to to pass the id which I then used to retrieve the book.

Either way, the part that I was missing were the special characters surrounding the string which let the app know that the url was a dynamic value.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `useParams` hook from `react-router-dom` like this:

```
let { book } = useParams();
```

or you can use `params` without destructuring like this:

```
let params = useParams();
let book = params.book
```

You can also send `data as state` to your url like this:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/home",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

EDIT:

in order to achieve what you have in mind you need to change this line in your `Main.js` file:

```
<Link to="/:book">{book.title}</Link>
```

to this:

```
<Link to={{pathname:'/book',state:{book:book}}}">{book.title}</Link>
```

and change your route accordingly:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={Main} />
    <Route path="/book" component={Single} />
</Switch>
```

Now in your `Single.js` File you can get `book object` like this:

first add `import 'useLocation' from 'react-router-dom';`

then

```
const location = useLocation();
const book = location.state.book; // You have book object here
```

Comment: hooks will work in functional components, seems like @dbrewster has a class component

Comment: withRouter(ComponentName)

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar Nope, He wants to use it in functional Component

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar Why did you give me down vote without understanding the question?

Comment: Who? anyway, I didn't do that.

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar , Then please give an upvote to make it 0 again, because I think I get that based on your comment

Comment: Well, I am at least getting a different error doing this. My problem now is that it is just reading whatever I type in aka :book

Comment: @dbrewster what do you mean? what else did you expect to get?

Comment: I was hoping to get the book object. I thought the colon made it dynamic so I would get whichever book I clicked on rather than the literal characters :book

Comment: And likewise I tried to just get the id so I could then just add an exra step to my Single.js to match the book with the id but it just goes to 3000/:id

Answer (score 0):

`<Route path="/:book" component={Single} />`
here book can be primitive data type like `string`,`number`,`bool` etc. you cannot send object as url parameter.

Change the route and send book as
`<Link to={{pathname:'/newRoute',state:{book:book}}}">{book.title}</Link>`