# passing a dynamic url with React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Thanks to everyone for your efforts to help me before at [How to pass and retrieve data over the url in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268385/how-to-pass-and-retrieve-data-over-the-url-in-react) I don't know why it wasn't working but I decided to simplify things and just pass a string instead of an object but it still isn't being read. Instead of having a dynamic url, it just passes the string ":i" or ":book.id" or whatever value I try to use in the Link tag.

App.js

```
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Main} />
          <Route path='/:i' component={Single} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Main.js

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <div id="main">
      {data.map((book, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i} className="squares">
            <img
              src={images[book.picture]}
              className="covers"
              alt="book cover"
            />
            <h3>
///////////////////////!!! HERE !!!/////////////////////////////////////
              **<Link to="/:i">{book.title}</Link>** 
            </h3>
```

Book.js

```
const Book = (props) => {

  let id = useParams();
  console.log("1", id); ////logs ':i'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not pass params in `Link` like this.

You pass parameter value, like id.

```
<Link to={`/${i}`}>
```

And then in route you receive it

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/:id" children={<Child />} />
</Switch>
```

[Here is doc with examples](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

Comment: I've tried that as well but using the template literal like that gives me a parsing error-  Line 42:24:  Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

Comment: sorry, forgot {}.